# How to call input id in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I'm trying to do some javascript work on this example:

```
var str= '<td><input id="product" type="checkbox" name="product' + i + '" value="Yes" />&nbsp; new product?</td>';
str = str+'<td><input type="text"class="form-control" id="number ' + i + '" name="number' + i + '" placeholder="GTIN"</td>'


<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var ckbox = $('#product');

    $('input').on('click', function () {
        if (ckbox.is(':checked')) {
            document.getElementById("number").readOnly = true;
            document.getElementById("number").value = "";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("number").readOnly = false;            
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

This seems to work only if my input checkbox is outside the *string builder*

Comment: Your checkbox is in `str`. When are you adding that to DOM?

Comment: Where do you append the var `str` in the DOM?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: See linked.  Your `$('input').on` runs before you add it to the DOM

Comment: `document.getElementById` calls for an element with the id given, from inside the DOM,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly you are trying to check if input created as string is checked or not. To do so, you can try something like this:

HTML

```
<div id="number">
  <table id='mytable'>

  </table>

</div>
```

JS

```
var str;
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    str = '<td><input id="product'+i+'" type="checkbox" checked name="product' + i + '" value="Yes" />new product?';
  str = str+'<td><input type="text"class="form-control" id="number ' + i + '" name="number' + i + '" placeholder="GTIN" data-checkbox-id="product'+i+'"></td>'
    $("#mytable").append(str);
}

$("[id*='product']").on("click", function(){
    var this_id = $(this).attr("id");

    if( $(this).is(":checked") )
      $("input[data-checkbox-id='"+this_id+"']").removeAttr("disabled");
    else
      $("input[data-checkbox-id='"+this_id+"']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
 });
```

Check the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/koky7zj1/11/ 
Is that what you are looking for?

**Edit**
See updated code. I'm glad I could help! :)

Comment: Hi Sebastian, what I'm trying to do is simply deactivate the textbox by clicking on the checkbox.
It's not working since it's created like the example above

Comment: The reason i didnt post the whole code, it's because it might be to long, would u mind it?

Comment: Ok, I understand. Check the code in my previous comment and let me know if this is what you was looking for

Comment: Yes that's exactly what im looking for, but the input has to be in the (var str). Since it's a table that keeps adding data. So imagine for each line you will have to be able to do this function

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/koky7zj1/6/ It isn't too hard to make it working for many elements

Comment: Very close!
But the textfield is actually next to the checkbox, i updated it here:
https://jsfiddle.net/koky7zj1/8/ 
So basically deactivate number instead
I will add it in my qustion

Comment: Now? https://jsfiddle.net/koky7zj1/11/ BTW Is there any reason why you put input and checkbox in two different columns? Whouldn't it be better to place them in one?

Comment: Yes it's supposed some sort of basket where customers add products for each line. This is why they are seperate. Thank you very much.
If you add you answer on top i will set it as correct answer!
Where can I read more about this btw? Working with javascript and elements outside DOM

Comment: Just updated my answer! :) There are many sites about this. Look here maybe: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp